# RichTextBox.DetectUrls working intermittently

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Environment: WinForms, .Net 4.5.1, VB.net, VS 2013

When loading plain text into a RichTextBox, it **does not consistently detect the Urls** in the plain text. I have set RichTextBox.DetectUrls but I am not sure that's the problem.

If I load the plain text, which can contain zero or more links, sometimes it will recognize the links (and format them so they can be clicked) and sometimes it will not. This statement is also true even when reloading the exact same text (so reloading will sometimes trigger the Urls to show as proper links and sometimes it will not).

I have not found anything here or elsewhere which discusses this. Are there any known reasons why this would be happening?

Comment: What are the links it is not finding?  A quick test, creating a Rich Text Box and typing into it, indicates that urls that start www or http:// are consistently shown as links.  Can you provide the text that is not working?

Comment: @DavidSetty They are all http:// or https:// links. A link which is not detected will often be detected by reloading the exact same text (so the link does not change but gets recognized by reloading the text). The opposite is true: Reloading can turn a detected link into a non-detected link. The problem is definitely not the link text it is something else.

Comment: So what else do you have going on?  Can you show some code please that may give a hint to what is happening?

Comment: @John please provide a [mcve] -> it allows us to properly help you, we're not magicians, just like you, nor do we know everything.

Comment: @Mafii I do understand and, of course, it is a reasonable request. However, the symptom is in a large complex app and when I create a simple app the problem does not reproduce. I will continue my efforts to create a proper sample to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Changing this property will not update text that is already present in the RichTextBox control; it only affects text which is entered after the property is changed.

Comment: @Zaggler The problems happens with **reloading** the same text

Comment: @John show how you set the text...that would be a start. I have an alternative solution if you want as well, but the default control should work. I am testing one now using same framework and VS and it works just fine...

Comment: @Zaggler This is part of a much larger system. They key things I have thought of are: DetectUrls is always true. I set rtb.Text = strMyText (which gets called from a timer). I do change rtb.Visible and I bring it to the front. The rtb is in a splitter control which is inside a usercontrol. That usercontrol is inside a spliter which is inside another spliter which is inside another splitter which is on a form. I have used all of these to try to make a sample app to show the error - I have not been able to reproduce the problem outside of the larger app. Theories is all I can hope for now. :-(

Comment: I understand, but at the same time here's what I am saying. You have a compound fracture to a leg and need surgery, but to perform the surgery you need an x-ray to show what's going on to see the extent of injuries and an approach. This is the same in theory, without code (doesn't have to be all of it) ***it's a guessing game***. Do you think the doctor would perform the surgery, I would say no. The first step in solving a problem is knowing there's a problem and secondly providing the key code in question to help replacate the problem. The only thing you have said it's much part of a bigger..

Comment: ..system and say a few key thoughts. This information is not the problem, your code is ***period***. If you want help you need to isolate only the code in question that we can replicate, otherwise the information you have provided is not adequate enough to help you.

Comment: @Zaggler I agree with you completely. I also could not give a meaningful answer to someone's question like this. I would not be hurt if it got closed for the lack of code.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you can't provide the code? I know where I work I can't post the exact code, I create a mock up of the issue that can be replicated.

Comment: I cannot post the code of the system. Sadly, a mock of does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: @John if the issue isn't recreated in another mock system (Presumably it works fine in that one?) then the issue isn't the `RichTextBox` itself, it's deeper than that

Answer (score 0):

Before adding any link to your `Richtextbox`, you need to clean it to make your links consistently work.

```
Richtextbox.clear()
```

This will help you for your consistently detecting the URL problem.